# Replace Scene in Spritekit with swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

I want to replace scene in my project.
I have made project using spritekit and swift in xcode version 6

Now when I try to write replace scene code using this

```
for touch:AnyObject in touches
        {
            let location=touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location)==self.playbutton
            {
                println("Go to the game!")


                var scene=PlayScene(size:self.size)
               let skView = self.view as SKView //ERROR

              }

        }
```

It gives me ERROR:

Downcast from 'SKView?' to 'SKView' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: `let skView = self.view? as SKView!`

Answer (score 2):

You have an "optional" problem over here.
Use this instead:

```
let skView = self.view? as SKView!
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the downcast part, that's what Xcode is saying, not as .....
Remove as.... and just unwrap with `let skView = self.view!` or an if/let statement if you're not sure about whether its nil:

```
if let skView = self.view{
skView.presentScene(...)
}
```

Watch out for strong reference cycles when you replace the scene.  Remember the view and scene are together, so..., you'll figure out.